# Fetching single Image from Multiple Uploaded Images

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables

- Products
- Featured Products
- Images

Each Product has multiple images but for homepage I want to display only one image for featured products.

This is the query I wrote but for products with 2 images it displays same product twice with different image. Any help?

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products a , featured_product b, image c WHERE b.p_id = a.product_id AND a.product_id = c.product_id ");
```

Comment: try using GROUP BY a.product_id

Comment: Thank you so much. Submit this as answer so I can select it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `GROUP BY a.product_id`